# I am trying to link JSP and Java file which is in package as I made JDBC connections in Conn.java class

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I'm learning Java Servlets and imported MySQL JDBC Driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar in Netbeans.I made Conn.java Class in package mypack

```
package mypack;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Conn{
      public Connection c;
      public Statement s;

public Conn(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///proj4","root","");
        s=c.createStatement();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
    }
    }
 }
```

Then I coded modifyuser.jsp

```
   <%@page import  ="java.sql.*"%>
   <%@page import = "mypack.Conn" %>


<%
   String u = "";
   mypack.Conn db = new mypack.Conn();
   ResultSet rs = db.s.executeQuery("select * from login");  // error!
   out.println("<table><th>Username<th>Password<th>type<th>Modify");
   while (rs.next()) {
       u = rs.getString("username");
   out.println("<table><th>Username<th>Password<th>type<th>Modify");

    }
%>
<tr>
   <td>
    <%= u%></td>
   <td>
    <%= rs.getString("password")%></td>
   <td>
    <%= rs.getString("type")%></td>
   <td>
    <a href ="modifyuser1.jsp" user ="<%=u%>">Modify</a></td>
</tr>
```

However on running this web (using server  Apache Tomcat/8.0.27, Netbeans8.2 as platform) and it is throwing error -

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /modifyuser.jsp at line 7

Root cause -- java.lang.NullPointerException
Can you please suggest me how to get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code need to inside `while` since your current code make it can not iterate the Resultset

```
<tr>
   <td>
    <%= u%></td>
   <td>
    <%= rs.getString("password")%></td>
   <td>
    <%= rs.getString("type")%></td>
   <td>
    <a href ="modifyuser1.jsp" user ="<%=u%>">Modify</a></td>
</tr>
```

So change your code to

```
<%
   String u = "";
   mypack.Conn db = new mypack.Conn();
   ResultSet rs = db.s.executeQuery("select * from login");  // error!
   out.println("<table><th>Username<th>Password<th>type<th>Modify");
  out.println("<table><th>Username<th>Password<th>type<th>Modify"); 
  while (rs.next()) {
%>
<tr>
   <td>
    <%= u%></td>
   <td>
    <%= rs.getString("password")%></td>
   <td>
    <%= rs.getString("type")%></td>
   <td>
    <a href ="modifyuser1.jsp" user ="<%=u%>">Modify</a></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: However the bigger issue was that I made the database in path --- jdbc:mysql:///proj4","root","" and entered the root password incorrectly. So this  should have been jdbc:mysql:///proj4","root",password  line 9 of Conn.java. Hence there was error in the above said line